# Properly including Angular directive's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I'm writing an Angular directive that needs a template. Loading a template in Angular is done by either embedding the template itself in the source code with `<script type="text/ng-template">` or by providing a url in the directive's configuration, like `templateUrl: "/path/to/template.html"`.

The first way is completely unacceptable for a 3rd party directive, because people won't `npm install` my directive and then do `include("node_modules/mydirective/template.html")`(or equivalent), it just feels dirty.

The second way won't work for the same reason. The template would be located inside the `node_modules` directory, which is not publicly accesible after packing/deploying a website.

My idea is to allow the developer to just include the template the same way the directive itself is included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/directive.js"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="/path/to/directive.html"></script>
```

The problem is that the second line won't work (browser will complain about unexpected characters, I assume because it still tries to parse the fetched content as JS.

I found that using `ng-include` instead of `script src` actually fetches the template. The problem with that is that by the time the template is fetched, my directive has already ran the `link` function and crashed (because it couldn't find the template).

Is there a way I can either delay my directive until the template is fetched or provide any sane way of loading the template?

Comment: try to use `ng-include` and put the template before the js script.

Comment: @أنيسبوهاشم Tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Templatecache for the win! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: I've seen others do this by using the template cache

Comment: @iH8 Yes, I was thinking about `$templateCache`, but then I still need to delay somehow the execution of the `link` funciton of my directive until the template is fetched. Thus my question, how can I delay the start of my directive?

Comment: I'de create a module for my directive(s) and insert the template(s) into the templatecache in the app's `run` method. That way they're immediately available when the directive(s) is/are used, they'll be already loaded.

Comment: @iH8 Inlining HTML inside a JS string feels like a very ugly way of doing things. I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: It might be ugly, but that is not uncommon, look at the ui-bootstrap code for example, they load all templates into cache in another module, but yeah, they are inlined in js strings. You could create a task (gulp/grunt/etc) as part of your "build" that inlines the template(s) from files...

Comment: During development one normally works with normal HTML template files, during build you turn them into templatecache with your build tool. I'm using Grunt and https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates but their are other options. You'll never need to read/develop with distribution so to hell with ugly, speed is what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about inline templating with just template, instead of templateUrl? If its a library, I feel it's the simplest way to bundle the directive and template for distribution

Comment: It will work (as I said in the comments below my question), but it feels extremely ugly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to delay evaluation of your directive is to write a wrapping directive that does the request for the template, then $compile and append the initial directive to the page in the request callback. Still, not so pretty.